# Separate the contents of a xml node with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm modifying my xml document with xsl and having trouble separating contents of a node. Here's an example:

**Input XML Document**

```
<root>
  <exampleNode>text 1 <insideNodeA/> text 2 <insideNodeB/> text 3</exampleNode>
  <exampleNode>text 4<insideNodeB/></exampleNode>
</root>
```

So in short, I have a node in which I can have some text, and various different nodes (or none) in any order. There is no way of knowing before hand if the content is only text, text and one of the nodes, only one of the nodes, text and both nodes in any order, etc.

Here's what I need to have:

**Wanted XML output**

```
<root>
 <unwrapped>
   <txt>text 1</txt>
   <reworkedNodeA/>
   <txt>text 2</txt>
   <reworkedNodeB/>
   <txt>text 3</txt>
 </unwrapped>
 <unwrapped>
   <txt>text 4</txt>
   <reworkedNodeB/>
 </unwrapped>
</root>
```

And of course I'm reworking the insideNodeA and B.

**My XSL code**

```
<xsl:template match="exampleNodee">
  <xsl:if test="count(*)&gt;0">
     <xsl:element name="unwrapped">
        <xsl:element name="txt"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The trouble is that this code only creates one "txt" element with the first text of the "exampleNode" and then applies the templates for each child nodes.

How can I retrieve the contents of "exampleNode" in the correct order and apply the correct templates to obtain the wanted output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I actually found the answer to my question, it was pretty simple after all.

So all I had to do was create a template matching "text()" and change my exammpleNode template as such :

```
<xsl:element name="unwrapped">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="text() | node()"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Using `<xsl:apply-templates/>` would suffice as it is a short form for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` and any "text" node is selected by the `node()` selection.

Comment: And XSLT allows you to use literal result elements e.g. `<unwrapped><xsl:apply-templates/></unwrapped>`, the use of `xsl:element` is mostly for computing names or namespaces of result elements at run-time.